# JLabel to JPanel, drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jpanel, jlabel

Basically at the moment, I can drag JLabels from one panel (selectpanel) to another Jlabel on another panel (storypanel).

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to create a JLabel on the storypanel, when I drag a JLabel from the selectpanel? For example if I had 5 JLabels on the select panel and I dragged each twice to the storypanel, I would get 10 Jlabels on the storypanel.

I hope that question is clear, please let me know if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Dragging operation is a combination of actions of removing a label from one panel and adding it to the other panel immediately. During this process you are referring a `JLabel` instance which is changing its container panel.

So track and debug your code for this logic, find out where the addition of label to *story panel* occurs. It should be something like `storyPanel.add(yourLabel);` Just after this statement create a new JLabel object and add it to the story panel. Isn't it easy?

Comment: I know how to add a JLabel to a JPanel, you may have misinterpreted me. I will need an unknown amount of JLabels added to a JPanel. So they need to be created dynamically I think, perhaps an array of JLabels.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you to find the statement where dragging finishes, and just after that statement you can create a list of JLabels.

Comment: Oh ok,sorry I understand you now. My mistake, makes sense. Thanks.